# Plugin for c++ development in eclipse(kepler)

Tags: c++, eclipse-plugin, mingw, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to install CDT in eclipse to set the c++ development environment.I want to install MinGW in eclipse.I have tried many ways but not succeed .

I have used following link :

https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Cygwin_HowTo.html

Is any one have any idea about how to set the c++ environment in eclipse?

What steps should I follow to get the CDT in eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refer this link 
http://max.berger.name/howto/cdt/ar01s04.jsp#installingcdt
write the latest version of eclipse you are suppose that the link is of eclipse galilieo and you are using kepler then you have write the kepler